# SQLAlchemy Parameterize an Unquoted Value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to dynamically create users in a database like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

def create_user(user: str, password: str):
    stmt = text("CREATE USER :user WITH PASSWORD :password")
    engine.execute(stmt, user=user, password=password)

create_user("bob", "password123")
```

But the problem with this is that SQLAlchemy will parameterize this query as:

`CREATE USER 'bob' WITH PASSWORD 'password123'"`

Which throws an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "'bob'"
LINE 1: CREATE USER 'bob' WITH PASSWORD 'password123'
```

This error is thrown because `bob` is supposed to be unquoted. The correct SQL output should in fact be:

`CREATE USER bob WITH PASSWORD 'password123'`

How can I prevent SQLAlchemy from wrapping the parameterized value in quotation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where standard query parameterization is not applicable, such as when trying to incorporate database object names into a SQL statement, we must resort to *dynamic SQL*:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    sql = "CREATE USER {} WITH PASSWORD {}".format("bob", "password123")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(sql)
```

(Obviously, care must be taken to avoid a visit from Little Bobby Tables.)

Comment: Got it, so there's no way to do this with SQLAlchemy (in a safe way) then. I think I'm going to go deeper into `psycopg2` to try to avoid a visit from Bobby Tables